# .htaccess to redirect custom error page and remove index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this code to remove index.php from URL and redirect to custom error page. `index.php` remove from URL is working fine but I don't know how to redirect custom error page code along with this.

I have tried this code, but not working

```
RewriteEngine on
<br>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d <br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$0 [QSA,L]<br>
```

ErrorDocument 400 /errors.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php
ErrorDocument 405 /errors.php
ErrorDocument 408 /errors.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.php
ErrorDocument 502 /errors.php
ErrorDocument 504 /errors.php

Is there solution for both ??

Answer (score 0):

Make some changes in config.php file Go to “your-project-or-domain/application/config/config.php”

You will find there below code.

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
//Replace above code with below code
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

It’s done but If you face still there is an issue then you need to change one more configuration in config.php file.
 You need to find below code

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO'; 
//Replace above code with below code
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: .htaccess code vary depending on hosting server. In some hosting server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use an extra ? in the last line of above code. The following line will be replaced with last line in applicable case:

```
// Replace last .htaccess line with this line
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: my config file already have same code above you have mentioned.